# Why is this string blank after the procedure returns it (Odin)?

Tags: odin-lang, odin

In the following small sample program, input is read from `stdin`. Printing the string value works inside `read_input`, but not in `main`. Surprisingly, the length (`len`) of the string *does* output in `main`, though the string output is blank.

```cpp
main :: proc() {
    fmt.print("$ ")
    input := read_input()

    // This will output the proper length
    fmt.println("returned string length:", len(input))

    // This will be empty
    fmt.println("returned string: ", input)
}

read_input :: proc() -> string {
    buf: [256]byte
    num_bytes, err := os.read(os.stdin, buf[:])

    if err < 0 {
        return "Error reading from stdin"
    }

    str := string(buf[:num_bytes - 1])

    // this will output the proper number of bytes
    fmt.println("bytes read: ", num_bytes)

    // this will output the string entered, minus the newline
    fmt.println("read string: ", str)

    return str
}
```

Example run/output:

```
$ hello
bytes read:  6
read string:  hello
returned string length: 5
returned string:
```

I've discovered that returning `strings.clone(str)` works but I'm not *really* understanding the problem above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Odin `string` is just a view over underlaying data buffer. In your case it points to `buf` which is local to `read_input` procedure. Once `read_input` returns its stack memory is gone, but returned string still points to it.

`strings.clone(str)` works because it allocates memory for a string copy and return string which points into this memory. In this case you'll need to `delete` it in `main` to avoid memory leak.

Comment: Is the fact that `len()` still works on the result of `read_input` in `main`, even though the stack memory is gone, just a bit of an illusion?

Comment: `len()` works because internally string stores pointer to data and length: https://odin-lang.org/docs/overview/#string-type And `len(input)` just reads this length field from returned string variable.